# react state change lambda fucntion code not called

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Inside the render() function I store some code in the const "success". But even the state is changed, the reference to "success"  between the Card.Footer tag below will never be called.
What's the reason for?

```
 render() {

let fields = this.props.fields.map(field => {

    return(
    <Form.Group controlId={field.col}>
      <Form.Row>
        <Form.Label>{field.label}</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control required={field.required} type="text" placeholder={field.label} />
      </Form.Row>
    </Form.Group>
    )
});

const success = () => {
    console.log('B');
    return(<small>Operation {this.props.operation} succeded.</small>);

    if(this.state.dml_success) {

    return(

        <div>Operation {this.props.operation} succeded.</div>
    )
    }
};

console.log('C');

return(
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem', backgroundColor: 'lightgrey' }}>
      <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{this.props.title}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      <Form onSubmit={this.dml.bind(this)}>
        {fields}
        <Form.Row>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        {this.props.operation}
          </Button>
        </Form.Row>
      </Form>
        </Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
      <Card.Footer className="text-muted">{success}</Card.Footer>
    </Card>     
)
}
```

}

Comment: Try `{success()}`, or `<success {...props} />` and accept props in your success function.  You might be getting a linting error compiling your component too because you have a return and the code below it will never execute, and you should return null at least if no conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined success as function so you need to add parentheses

```
{success()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the function `{success()}` instead of `{success}`.